# User tabs and actions

Tags: hooks, routes

I have a custom module and in `hook_menu` have defined the items below.

I have created a new user tab below:

```
$items["user/%user/TAB"] = array(
    "title"             => t("TAB"),
    "page callback"     => "FUNCTION1",
    "page arguments"    => array(1),
    "type"              => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

and several actions (showing 2 below):

```
$items["user/%user/TAB/ACTION"] = array(
    "title"             => t("ACTION"),
    "page callback"     => "FUNCTION1",
    "page arguments"    => array(1),
    "type"              => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
);

$items["user/%user/TAB/ACTION2"] = array(
    "title"             => t("ACTION2"),
    "page callback"     => "FUNCTION2",
    "page arguments"    => array(1),
    "type"              => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
);
```

New tab shows and when I click on it, I get my action links as expected. But when I click on an action, I lose the tabs! The breadcrumb is accurate but no tabs.

How do I keep the user tabs?

Comment: Perhaps you should define a root item first. E.g. $items["user/%user/myroot"] $items["user/%user/myroot/TAB"]

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Unrelated: You should not use t() inside hook_menu(). Instead, just type the literal title in English. The default title callback is t(), so all your titles will go through t() automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid that it took me so long to try this:

```
$items["user/%user/TAB/ACTION"] = array(
    "title"             => t("ACTION"),
    "page callback"     => "FUNCTION1",
    "page arguments"    => array(1),
    "type"              => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items["user/%user/TAB/ACTION2"] = array(
    "title"             => t("ACTION2"),
    "page callback"     => "FUNCTION2",
    "page arguments"    => array(1),
    "type"              => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```